# use jwplayer to get current play time

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I am using [jwplayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/15990/about-the-jw-player) to play embedded video,
the [javascript api](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/16023/getting-values-from-the-player) tells me

`jwplayer("mediaplayer").getPosition()`

will get the current position, but my result is `undefined`

Can anyone help me get the correct resilts

Comment: Can you include **your** HTML and JavaScript here - it works fine when using the example HTML and JavaScrip

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/AMXvU/) just how the documentation specifies :

```
<div id="container"></div>


jwplayer("container").setup({
    file: "http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/nPripu9l-60830.mp4",
    flashplayer: "http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf",
    image: "http://content.bitsontherun.com/thumbs/nPripu9l-480.jpg",
    height: 270,
    width: 480
});
var state = jwplayer("container").getState();
var elapsed = jwplayer("container").getPosition();
```

Comment: i try test it ,  but it is result undefined ;

Comment: @wumengjun can you add **your** html and JavaScript to your question - I created a jsfiddle (linked to in my answer) and it works fine there

Comment: give me you email ,i post demo to you , can't be use ?

Comment: @manseuk Isn't there an event that updates regularly so I can track the time?http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html#event%3aplayheadUpdate

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 the page you link to is not JWPlayer - if you have question post a question not a comment

Comment: @ManseUK hello sir..  I have also implemented this code to get play time and other things. Its working fine for all android devices and desktop. But it not return all these details for Iphone and windows phone. Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the elapsed value with an HLS live stream? Is it from load or from the beginning of the broadcast.

Answer (score 3):

How does your HTML and JavaScript look? Without seeing these, I can only assume the following.

According to the [API documentation](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12540/javascript-api-reference#GettingStarted) on the website this can be achieved without specifying a container, like so...

```
jwplayer().getPosition()
```

Comment: Works with a container specified - [check out my example here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10597786/572939)

Comment: I thought it would; the container is optional however.

Comment: Indeed, like I said in my post, without any HTML mark-up in the original post, we can only assume. ;)